# pumping lemma - choice of partition

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language, pumping-lemma

there is some thing in pumping lemma that I don't understand it.
I think about application to prove irregularity of language.
We have for each word (actual length) find partition:  $xyz$ such that  $\forall i \ge 0 xy^iz \in L$.
So we can find word, but tell me - if we can choose partition ? (so choose $y$) ?  Maybe we should check each possible partition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that all regular langauges satisfy the pumping lemma, which we capture by the following informal proposition:
$$\text{regular}\implies\text{pumping lemma}.$$
Applying *modus tollens* (a.k.a. contrapositive), we get
$$\neg\text{pumping lemma}\implies\neg\text{regular}.$$
Therefore, **to prove a language is not regular, it suffices to show that it does not satisfy the pumping lemma**. For any regular language $L$,
the pumping lemma states the following:
$$
\exists p\geq1(\forall w(\left|w\right|\geq p\Rightarrow\exists x,y,z(w=xyz\wedge\left|y\right|\geq1\wedge\left|xy\right|\leq p\wedge\forall i\geq0(xy^{i}z\in L))))
$$
Taking the negation of this statement,
$$
\forall p\geq1(\exists w(\left|w\right|\geq p\wedge\forall x,y,z(w=xyz\Rightarrow(y=\epsilon\vee\left|xy\right|>p\vee\exists i\geq0(xy^{i}z\notin L)))))
$$
As you can see, we have to show that for all pumping lengths $p$, there exists a word $w$ at least as long as the pumping length $p$ such that **for all partitions** $w=xyz$, at least one of the following is true: (i) $y$ is the empty string (i.e. $w=xz$), (ii) $|xy|$ is greater than the pumping length, or (iii) there exists an $i$ such that the pumped string $xy^{i}z$ is not in $L$.

If any one of (i) or (ii) is true for a partition, we need not consider it in our proof by contradiction. Therefore, **we can look only at partitions for which (i) and (ii) are false, and try to show that (iii) is true**. [The example on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Use_of_lemma) is quite helpful in demonstrating this. It is paraphrased below:

> Let $L=\{a^{n}b^{n}\colon n\geq0\}$ be a language, which we will prove
>   to be not regular. Suppose $L$ satisfies the pumping lemma. Let $p$ be an arbitrary pumping length. Let
>   $w=a^{p}b^{p}$, and note that $|w|\geq p$. Let $w=xyz$ be an arbitrary
>   partition of $w$. Suppose $y$ is not empty and $|xy|\leq p$. Since
>   $|xy|\leq p$ and $w=a^{p}b^{p}$, $y=a^{k}$ for some $1\leq k\leq p$.
>   We can now "pump" to conclude that $w^\prime=xy^{2}z$ is a word in the language $L$. This is, however, a contradiction, since $w^\prime$ has more $a$ characters than $b$ characters.

Comment: So always it is sufficient to check (iii) ? Why didn't you check (i) or (ii) in example ?

Comment: Fix a partition $w=xyz$. If any one of (i) and (ii) are true, then $y=\epsilon\vee\left|xy\right|>p\vee\exists i\geq0(xy^{i}z\notin L)$ is true. Therefore, suppose neither (i) nor (ii) are true, we need to show (iii) to show that the statement is true.

Comment: What about version for CFG languages ?

Comment: You would just take the negation of the statement on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages